# ActiveMQ failover seems not to work

Tags: activemq-classic, mom

I have super simple scenario: one broker and one consumer with durable subscription.
This is the code of my consumer app:

```
package test;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import pojo.Event;
import pojo.StockUpdate;

public class Consumer
{

    private static transient ConnectionFactory factory;
    private transient Connection connection;
    private transient Session session;
    public static int counter = 0;

    public Consumer(String brokerURL) throws JMSException
    {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.setClientID("CLUSTER_CLIENT_1");
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException
    {

        try
        {
            // extract topics from the rest of arguments
            String[] topics = new String[2];
            topics[0] = "CSCO";
            topics[1] = "ORCL";

            // define connection URI
            Consumer consumer = new Consumer("failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectAttempts=-1&useExponentialBackOff=true");

            for (String stock : topics)
            {
                try
                {
                    Destination destination = consumer.getSession().createTopic("STOCKS." + stock);
                    // consumer.getSession().
                    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = consumer.getSession().createDurableSubscriber((Topic) destination, "STOCKS_DURABLE_CONSUMER_" + stock);
                    messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new Listener());
                }
                catch (JMSException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Session getSession()
    {
        return session;
    }

}

class Listener implements MessageListener
{

    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String json = textMessage.getText();
            Event event = StockUpdate.fromJSON(json, StockUpdate.class);
            System.out.println("Consumed message #:" + ++Consumer.counter + "\n" + event);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my activemq.xml

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="R6_cluster_broker1" persistent="true">

        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector uri="static:(failover:(tcp://remote_master:61616,tcp://remote_slave:61617))"/>
        </networkConnectors>

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="/work/temp/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <!-- <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/> -->
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

When I have both broker and consumer running and then stop the broker my consumer exits few moments after. As far I understood it must attempt to reconnect, but it is not the case. What am I doing wrong, please advise.

!NOTE! I launch my consumer in Eclipse, i do not build a standalone jar for this task.

I have updated my broker to the latest 5.9.1 and did the same to my consumer. Result is the same - after I stop the broker my consumer dies few seconds after. It works fine if broker is up and running.

Comment: I have updated my broker to the latest 5.9.1 and did the same to my consumer. Result is the same - after I stop the broker my consumer dies few seconds after. It works fine if broker is up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the problem was actually in my code: there was nothing that would prevent main thread from exiting. Since thread that implements failover is a daemon thread, consumer app terminated right after there was nothing to hold on to (no non-daemon threads).

Comment: I've just stumbled on the same "issue". Thanks for confirming the cause!

What kind of solution have you implemented to avoid the main thread to terminate?

Comment: As far as I remember, I've added shutdown hook.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who **can't** setup the failover via the URI/URL parameter in the ConnectionFactory ,because of schema not found in **ARTEMIS** :

As far as I know in the **ActiveMQ** the URL is the following:

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:51516)?randomize=false
```

But in **Artemis** the above will fail ,because of schema not found so remove just the `failover:` prefix:

```
(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:51516)?randomize=false
```

Comment: In attempting to migrate from the regular ActiveMQ client to Artemis, this helped me out.

Background: I can't move on to Jakarta EE9 with the old client while Artemis provides one that compiles on the Jakarta namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using a version of ActiveMQ that has a bug which causes there to be all daemon threads which means there's nothing to keep the client running.  Upgrade to a later version such as v5.9.1 and see if that helps.  If not post more information as you haven't really provided much.

Comment: Tim, I am using Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0
What extra information would you like me to post?

Comment: I can confirm the behavior with `5.13.2`.